# quarkus-cxf native build failes - UnresolvedElementException - Discovered unresolved method during parsing

Tags: cxf, quarkus

Good day to all :-)

I am using the quarkus-cxf extension and have now encountered the following problem.

In JVM mode everything works fine. Thank you very much for your library.

But I have errors in native mode. For a tip what I am probably doing wrong, I am very grateful …

Quarkus Version: 1.7.1.Final
quarkus-cxf Version: https://github.com/shumonsharif/quarkus-cxf/blob/master/pom.xml

Error occurs on

**mvn clean package** -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true -Dquarkus.container-image.registry=nfrt-docker-staging-local.repo.pnet.ch -Dquarkus.container-image.tag=latest **-Pnative**

```
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.apache.cxf.staxutils.validation.W3CMultiSchemaFactory.<init>(). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
```

Detailed message:
Trace:
at parsing org.apache.cxf.staxutils.validation.Stax2ValidationUtils.getValidator(Stax2ValidationUtils.java:164)
Call path from entry point to org.apache.cxf.staxutils.validation.Stax2ValidationUtils.getValidator(Endpoint, ServiceInfo):
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.validation.Stax2ValidationUtils.getValidator(Stax2ValidationUtils.java:136)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.validation.Stax2ValidationUtils.setupValidation(Stax2ValidationUtils.java:115)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.validation.WoodstoxValidationImpl.setupValidation(WoodstoxValidationImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataReader.validate(XMLStreamDataReader.java:231)
at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataReader.read(XMLStreamDataReader.java:115)
at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataReader.read(XMLStreamDataReader.java:83)
at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataReader.read(XMLStreamDataReader.java:67)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareInInterceptor.handleMessage(BareInInterceptor.java:131)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.MultipleEndpointObserver.onMessage(MultipleEndpointObserver.java:98)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream$1.run(HTTPConduit.java:1201)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatures.report(UnsupportedFeatures.java:126)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:750)
... 8 more
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.apache.cxf.staxutils.validation.W3CMultiSchemaFactory.(). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.reportUnresolvedElement(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:259)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedMethod(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:249)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedInvoke(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:203)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeSpecial(BytecodeParser.java:1811)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeSpecial(BytecodeParser.java:1801)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5339)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3423)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3230)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1088)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:982)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:214)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:225)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:352)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.doParse(MethodTypeFlow.java:322)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureParsed(MethodTypeFlow.java:311)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:112)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.DefaultAnalysisPolicy$DefaultSpecialInvokeTypeFlow.onObservedUpdate(DefaultAnalysisPolicy.java:373)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.notifyObservers(TypeFlow.java:470)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.update(TypeFlow.java:542)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.BigBang$2.run(BigBang.java:530)
at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(CompletionExecutor.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
... 5 more
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retry with last version on https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkiverse-cxf